Дочерний div с absolute всегда внизу прокрученного родительского div, на чистом css
Столкнулся с непоняткой. Есть родительский div с фиксированной высотой и автоматической вертикальной прокруткой "по требованию". Внутри него есть первый div потомок с position: absolute и высотой большей, нежели высота родителя (вследствие чего появляется вертикальный скролл) и второй div потомок, также с position: absolute и произвольной высотой. Мне необходимо, чтобы второй потомок всегда был внизу родителя, даже если первый потомок гораздо больше по высоте. А получается, что второй потомок при его bottom: 0 находится внизу видимой части родителя и плевать ему, что у родителя есть скролл и низ этого парента гораздо ниже чем видимая часть. И еще момент: у первого потомка, который с большой высотой, эта высота не статичная, она формируется контентом, в примере она указана протсо для указания размеров, кто есть кто.
Код


.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child_big {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  height: 2000px;
}

.child_small {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child_big">Контент первого потомка</div>
  <div class="child_small">Контент второго потомка</div>
</div>




Мoжет речь о sticky ?

Со sticky было бы хорошо, но у меня получилось, что потомка со sticky уже никак не сместить, допустим, на дополнительные 20px ниже, стики как прилип четко к низу и все. Поэтому и стал смотреть в сторону absolute

как вариант можно использовать дополнительную обертку для первого (который большой и должен прокручиваться) дочернего элемента, чтобы в этой обертке и организовать прокручивание. Если конечно это допустимо
